# Dependency injection of Generic subtype with Spring

Tags: java, spring, generics, dependency-injection, autowired

I am trying to inject specific Generic bean to Generic subtype, but Spring is unable to resolve dependency. By removing type from the bean, everything works as expected. Here is an example:

```
public class AbstractFrom{
    // ...
}

public class EmployyForm extends AbstractFrom{
    // ...
}

public class CompanyForm extends AbstractFrom{
    // ...  
}

abstract class AbstractBean<T extends AbstractFrom>{

    public abstract void calculate(T form); 
}

@Component
public CompanyBean extends AbstractBean<CompanyForm>{

    public void calculate(CompanyForm form){
        // specific impl
    }   
}

@Component
public EmployeeBean extends AbstractBean<EmployyForm>{

    public void calculate(EmployyForm form){
        // specific impl
    }   
}
```

Here is a target class:

```
 @Service
    public BaseService{

        @Autowire
        public AbstractBean<AbstractFrom> baseBean; // <- NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

        // @Autowire
        // public AbstractBean baseBean; <- Injection works as is expected
    }
```

Depends of active profile is initialized only `CompanyBean` or `EmployeeBean`, never both. I've also tried set the same name given beans and us `@Qualifier` annotation.

Does exist any way how inject this bean using diamond syntax? Does Spring is able to resolve given dependency? Using Spring 4.2.x.

---

**Edit:** 
With Spring 4.3 is should be possible. See [Juergen Hoeller's talk](https://youtu.be/8Uyut8JjH34?t=40m13s)

Comment: Have you tried to autowire `public AbstractBean<? extends AbstractFrom> baseBean;`?

Answer (score 0):

I know you are probably not going to like this, but why not separate out the EmployeeForm and the CompanyForm to 2 separate base forms, and then in the BaseService make **TWO** entires, for the Autowire.

This is not a Spring answer per se, but that is what I would do, as a quick work around to see if it would work.
Separating them is not a terrible design compromise.

Comment: It would solved the issue, but this is not solution in my case because I would have to duplicate quite a lot of code. In therms of maintainability it is worse solution. Thanks anyway.